# missing default english keyboard ime

Tags: keyboard, input-methods

My tablet has the English language as an option. but under keyboard and input methods, chinese is the only option.  Is there a way I can install the default android english ime?

Comment: How do you know it has English language as an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Android are you using? If it's 4.0 and up then you can install the default Keyboard from Google from here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin